# Broadcastreceiver creating multiple instances of TelephonyManager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

This is my BroadcastReceiver

```
public class PlayAudio extends BroadcastReceiver {
 
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(new CustomPhoneStateListener(context), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```

This is my Custom PhoneStateListener Class

```
public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    Context context; 
    
    public CustomPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            Log.d("PHONEA", "IDLE");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
           Log.d("PHONEA", "OFFHOOK");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            Log.d("PHONEA", "RINGING");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, AudioService.class);
            context.startService(intent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my service

```
public class AudioService extends Service{
    private static final String TAG = "PHONEA";
    MediaPlayer player;
    
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate -> TODO");
        }
}
```

My question is that every time I receive data in Broadcast receiver I create a new instance of the `TelephonyManager`. So when I view the logcat the first time I get "RINGING", the second time "RINGING" "RINGING" and so on. When should I create my `telephonylistener` in order to have only one instance?

Regards,
Nicos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting call on your receiver(Asssuming you are listening for PhoneState) every time the phone state change.

You should put some check in your receiver and instatiate the `TelephonyManager` for the first time only.

Comment: since i am a noob could you please provide me with a simple demo as how to do that?

Comment: take any boolean and check if it is false then instantiate and set the boolean true else skip .. and make this false when your task completes .. Save this boolean is SharedPreference...